# Is there any way to remove VSTS agent without PAT?

Tags: azure-devops

I'm trying to remove a VSTS agent from a system, but I no longer possess the Personal Access Token (PAT) originally used during setup. An answer on [this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/431f9a06-db69-49d4-8bc0-3bff9911f959/vsts-private-agent-authentication-with-pat-personal-access-tokens?forum=TFService) states that I can just delete the agent from the VSTS web UI, but I don't see that option besides nuking the entire agent pool (which is not a great option for us).

When I try to run `config.cmd remove`, these are my results:

```
PS C:\agent> .\config.cmd remove
Removing agent from the server
Enter authentication type (press enter for PAT) >
Enter personal access token >
Enter personal access token > Exiting...
```

Answer (score 67, accepted):

First, it’s better to remove VSTS agent through `config.cmd remove` command and the PAT is required, you don’t need to use original PAT, you can apply a new PAT with Agent Pools (read, manage) scope and use it to remove agent.

Secondly, without PAT:

Deleting agent from server:

[image]

Deleting agent service in local system through sc command if it is running as service: `sc delete [service name]`.

After that, you can delete the agent files.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I never thought to just use a new/working PAT, but when you think about it, it makes sense - all you're trying to do is prove you're authenticated and allowed to perform the action. Also, I could have sworn that X button to delete agents was not showing up for us last week...

Comment: I used the `config.cmd remove` command to delete the service and skipped the PAT entry - I manually removed the Agent from the pool in Azure Devops portal.

Comment: This will not remove all agent information on the server, which prevents you from reinstalling a new agent. To remove everything run `config.cmd remove` and supply a random PAT string (must be valid length/format though - just generate a new one). It will fail to remove the agent in VSTS/DevOps (which you must do manually as stated above) but it will continue and remove the remaining agent data and allow reinstallation afterwards. Handy if you installed a x86 agent on an x64 server by accident ;-)

Comment: This is headache on Server Core over WinRM. `config.cmd remove` tells `Cannot read keys when either application does not have a console or when console input has been redirected. Try Console.Read.`. 
`.\config.cmd remove --token <token>` tells `VS30063: You are not authorized to access https://<url>.`

No service is present on local PC and agent deleted on remote. And this is being done 10 minutes after install, so token is still healthy. Ehh.

Comment: Alright, you can just remove agent folder and extract it again and retry. Because running config creates hidden folders: `.agent`, `.credentials`, `.credentials_rsaparams` - if they are present, it will complain. Afterwards it allows to retry reconfiguration (given devops agent removed from web portal)

Comment: @JanisVeinbergs When generating the token, select "All accessible organizations" in the Organization dropdown. That fixes VS30063 for Azure DevOps Server.

Comment: @mhbuur I clicked on add resource, it created the script for me with PAT within it. I used that to removed the agent and it succeeded :-) Cheers!