# How to uninstall or remove configuration of a deployment pool or deployment agent

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent, azure-devops-server-2019, azure-devops-server

I am using Azure DevOps Server (TFS), and I register deployment pool agents in my test and production servers, now iIneed to uninstall or remove the configuration on my server and in my UI how can I do that there are a script to run or just delete the files or what could you please help me with that.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to do 2 things:

1) Go to the agent folder (where he installed) and run `config.cmd` with the flag `remove`. if you are in the agent folder run this in the command line:

```
./config remove
```

2) Go to the Deployment Group (in the UI) and click on the `...` near the group and then `Delete` (to delete all the group, if you want only the agents so go inside and do the same thing there).

Comment: You may also want to remove Deployment Pool as removing Deployment Group is not removing Deployment Pool explicitly.

Comment: Great!  Thanks!!  Link to where in the documentation that this is explained?

Comment: @AdamCox https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops#remove-and-re-configure-an-agent

Comment: And in case it asks for PAT and you don't have it, refer this - [Is there any way to remove VSTS agent without PAT?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46396872/1176573)

Answer (score 1):

If you are in linux navigate to azagent folder and then

`sudo ./svc.sh uninstall`

Refer to :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-linux?view=azure-devops