# How to remove pipeline's access to self hosted agent (without the original PAT or access to the azure devops)?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Following are steps followed to setup the self hosted agent.

1. Create a azure devops organization
2. Create personal access token (PAT) with manage agent permissions
3. Create an agent in azure devops
4. On the target machine download the zip, unzip, run `./config.cmd`
5. Enter url, PAT

Now the agent is ready to be used for release pipeline deployments. Now I want to remove the agent so I run `.\config remove`. It asks me for the PAT which I don't remember.

I don't have access to the azure devops anymore (so cannot generate new PAT). My goal (ad this question) is regarding removal of the agent service from the machine. Whether or not it removes the agent from the azure devops is irrelevant. Any advise?

Maybe it is sufficient to just delete the `C:\agent` folder after the above command error?

[image]

Comment: Just create new pat use it once and revoke it

Comment: Indeed. You should regenerate your PAT, reconfigure your agent with the new PAT and then remove config using the PAT

Comment: I don't have access to the Azure devops anymore

Comment: Maybe after the service stops all I need to do is delete the `c:\agent` folder?

Comment: Than just remove the agent manually from your computer that is.

Comment: Does remove mean deletion of the `c:\agent` folder? Or is there anywhere else that the service gets installed - for example via windows add/remove programs?

Comment: DevOps use self host agent require you first run the agent, if you even delete the entire agent folder, of course the devops will not be able to access to the agent any more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will leave formal answer, just in case.

In your case, you do not have access to Azure DevOps longer and you are not able to generate or re-generate PAT token. No problem, it is not big issue, the agent software is a connection between your (a) Server and (b) Azure DevOps. So if you do not have access to Azure DevOps, you can not do any thing about it. What you need to focus on, is uninstalling the agent software from (a) Server so it is no longer connected to (b) Azure DevOps.

Normally to remove agent, just use `.\config remove` as you already have done in our question, and ignore server errors, the only reason server requires PAT again, is to allow removing the agent from Azure DevOps remotely, hence you do not have access Azure DevOps longer, just ignore the messages, it will removing the files. Delete the folder and that is it.

In case you get troubling or fail removing files using `.\config remove`, than you have to do manual removal. You have 2 options below:

- If you have installed the agent as Service.
  Stop the service and deleting agent service in local system through: `sc delete [service name]`.
- If it is just running in command line.
  Stop the command line.

When one of the options is done. delete your agent folder. Now your Server is not longer connected to Azure DevOps. And you can use it for another Azure DevOps agent installation.

Reference:

- [Is there any way to remove VSTS agent without PAT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46366929/is-there-any-way-to-remove-vsts-agent-without-pat)
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops
- https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/issues/528

Comment: As shown in the question, the `.\config remove` command stops and removes the service. So no need for `sc delete [service name]` I suppose? I think all that is needed is to run `.\config remove` and ignore the server related errors (see screenshot in my question) and then delete the `C:\agent` folder. Correct? If so can you update this in the answer so I can mark it answered.